# Python transform list of dictionaries into another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in python. Here is a contrieved example with hair color and race.

```
some_list = [
        {'blond': 3, 'race': 'WHITE'},
        {'black': 4, 'race': 'WHITE'},
        {'light brown': 6, 'race': 'WHITE'},
        {'black': 2, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'},
        {'blond': 1, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'},
        {'dark brown': 1, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'}
]
```

The hair color is one of the keys and the value for the hair color is the count of how many people have that hair color for the given race. I do not know how many hair colors there are nor do I know how many races there are. I want to transform this list to include counts of ALL hair colors for ALL races such that the result would include 0 counts for colors not listed for a given race:

```
some_list = [
        {'blond': 3, 'race': 'WHITE'},
        {'black': 4, 'race': 'WHITE'},
        {'light brown': 6, 'race': 'WHITE'},
        {'dark brown': 0, 'race': 'WHITE'},
        {'black': 2, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'},
        {'blond': 1, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'},
        {'dark brown': 1, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'},
        {'light brown': 0, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'}
]
```

For the life of me I can't think of a simple 'python' way to do this easily. Surely there is a trick to this? Anyone know a succient way to solve this?

Comment: Show us what you tried. I also think that the data structure you chose is a bit weird.

Comment: You can iterate, and use `set(..)` to find unique colors/races, then use `itertools.product(..)` to find all combinations. Fill zeros where you dont have entry in `some_list`. Tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Thats where I'm stuck...I have a unique list already...as shown in the first code snippet...but I don't know a good way to iterate through and fill in the missing hair colors for given race. How does itertools.product(..) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, and you are able to use external libraries, you could accomplish this with [`pandas`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(some_list, index=None)

df = df.groupby(by='race').count().transpose()

for col in df.columns:
    rw = df.loc[df[col] == 0]
    dic = {rw.index[0]: 0, 'race': col}
    some_list.append(dic)

# output:
# some_list = [
#     {'blond': 3, 'race': 'WHITE'},
#     {'black': 4, 'race': 'WHITE'},
#     {'light brown': 6, 'race': 'WHITE'},
#     {'black': 2, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'},
#     {'blond': 1, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'},
#     {'dark brown': 1, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'},
#     {'light brown': 0, 'race': 'AFRICAN_AMERICAN'},
#     {'dark brown': 0, 'race': 'WHITE'}
# ]
```